# Swift: Accessing array value in array of dictionaries

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I am currently struggling with obtaining a value from an array inside an array of dictionaries. Basically I want to grab the first "[0]" from an array stored inside an array of dictionaries. This is basically what I have:

```
var array = [[String:Any]]()
var hobbies:[String] = []
var dict = [String:Any]()
```

viewDidLoad Code:

```
dict["Name"] = "Andreas"
hobbies.append("Football", "Programming")
dict["Hobbies"] = hobbies
array.append(dict)
```

/// - However, I can only display the name, with the following code:

```
var name = array[0]["Name"] as! String
```

- But I want to be able to display the first value in the array stored with the name, as well. How is this possible?

And yes; I know there's other options for this approach, but these values are coming from Firebase (child paths) - but I just need to find a way to display the array inside the array of dictionaries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **But I want to be able to display the first value in the array stored with the name??** u mean with key and value??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know `"Hobbies"` is a valid key and its dictionary value is an array of `String`, then you can directly access the first item in that array with:

```
let hobby = (array[0]["Hobbies"] as! [String])[0]
```

but this will crash if `"Hobbies"` isn't a valid key or if the value isn't `[String]`.

A safer way to access the array would be:

```
if let hobbies = array[0]["Hobbies"] as? [String] {
    print(hobbies[0])
}
```

Comment: Great! Just what I needed! Thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you use a model class/struct things get easier

### Given this model struct

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    var hobbies: [String]
}
```

### And this dictionary

```
var persons = [String:Person]()
```

### This is how you put a person into the dictionary

```
let andreas = Person(name: "Andreas", hobbies: ["Football", "Programming"])
persons[andreas.name] = Andreas
```

### And this is how you do retrieve it

```
let aPerson = persons["Andreas"]
```